# Interval Time subtraction in Java

Tags: java, time, intervals

I was trying to find the difference in time (HH:mm:ss.SSS) in Java, where each time can be more than 24 hours. `SimpleDateFormat` does not support time which is greater than 24 hours.

For example,

Time A = 36:00:00.00
Time B = 23:00:00.00

I would like to get the answer of 13:00:00.00. (13 hours).

Does any one know whether there are any Java libraries that can perform the subtraction. Also would like to know whether time addition is possible with the Java library.

Comment: Do you mean, "36:00:00.00" and "23:00:00.00" are supplied as strings which have to be parsed?

Comment: `36:00:00.00` isn't a valid time, it is at best an interval of time expressed the same way common time is expressed.

Comment: Ah, I like to count my time from about 11:00 (when I wake up) to 28:30 (when I go to bed).

Comment: Hi T-Bull, yes. they are Strings that need to be parsed.

Comment: Hi Jarrod Roberson, you are right. But this is a problem I have and i intend to fix it.

Comment: Hi Paulo Ebermann, interesting example.

Answer (score 11):

**You don't need a third party library**

This is simple math, and doesn't directly appear to have anything to do with `Date` `DateTime` or `Timestamp` instances, but does appear to be `interval` related, and there is built in functionality into the JDK >= 1.5 with `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` to handle just this type of math without introducing any dependencies.

Here is the code to parse your input and convert it into milliseconds, which you can then convert back into whatever `String` format you want, I conveniently chose the format you requested.

[java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) is a little hidden gem that most people don't know about that kind of snuck in to 1.5. It is kind of criminal that this class is buried in the `java.util.concurrent` package and no one seems to know about it.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{
    private static long parseInterval(final String s)
    {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})\\.(\\d{3})$");
        final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches())
        {
            final long hr = Long.parseLong(m.group(1)) * TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1);
            final long min = Long.parseLong(m.group(2)) * TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);
            final long sec = Long.parseLong(m.group(3)) * TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1);
            final long ms = Long.parseLong(m.group(4));
            return hr + min + sec + ms;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(s + " is not a supported interval format!");
        }
    }

    private static String formatInterval(final long l)
    {
        final long hr = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l);
        final long min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hr));
        final long sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hr) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(min));
        final long ms = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(l - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hr) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(min) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(sec));
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", hr, min, sec, ms);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String s1 = "36:00:00.000";
        final String s2 = "23:00:00.000";

        final long i1 = parseInterval(s1);
        final long i2 = parseInterval(s2);

        System.out.println(formatInterval(i1 - i2));
    }
}
```

the output is

```
13:00:00.000
```

I assume you meant for the last number to be `milliseconds` which should have a resolution of 3 digits.

Comment: @Steve Kuo, there's no such thing as "too much `final`"

Comment: @Steve Kuo - [The Final Word on Final](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/05/the-final-word-on-final/)

Comment: For local variables I find `final` clutters up the code. But it's personal choice of style. +1 for a non-Joda related answer.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: no, it's not a matter of personal choice of style.  You've been given reading you decided to ignore.  In addition to what is said in the fine link posted by *Jarrod Roberson*, you should also know that using *final* for local variables helps intelligent IDEs (like IntelliJ IDEA) give even more intelligent warnings.  It also helps avoid silly distraction mistakes.  It's not a matter of style, stop arguing.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r Just because you sited some reading doesn't make it the concrete correct way of doing things. Anyone can put their opinion in writing but that doesn't it make the absolute truth.

Comment: @Steve not absolute, but *empirical* truth.

Comment: +1 Jarrod Roberson. This is the first time i have come across TimeUnit! Please let me try your code out before clicking on any thing else.!

Comment: @Jarrod I agree this is a nice, working solution (+1). But it's still a hack using tools that weren't explicitly created to do what you do with them.

Comment: how is using a class called `TimeUnit` that was explicitly created to manipulate units of time a _hack_? Look at how it is used in the `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. It was created explicitly for manipulating intervals of time that are not directly associated with `Date` information.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete solution using JodaTime. I dare say there's no comparably easy and elegant way to do it using `java.util` or `java.util.concurrent` apis:

```
public static int getHoursBetween(final String date1, final String date2){
    final DateTimeFormatter fmt =
        DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("HH:mm:ss.SS")
            .withChronology(
                LenientChronology.getInstance(
                    GregorianChronology.getInstance()));
    return Hours.hoursBetween(
        fmt.parseDateTime(date1),
        fmt.parseDateTime(date2)
    ).getHours();
}
```

([`LenientChronology`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/chrono/LenientChronology.html) makes sure that values like 38:00:00.00 are supported)

Comment: Hi Sean Patrick Floyd, Thanks! I got really confused reading the Chonologies that Joda-Time supported. I'll try out the code and get back on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which is a complete library for dealing with times and dates in Java, including arithmetic on intervals.

Comment: Because joda-time is a complete library for dealing with time intervals.  There's no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: I suppose I just don't understand why suggesting a third-party library is a suitable answer, or why there's a need to use a third-party library at all. but whatever, to each his own.

Comment: If you get paid to reinvent wheels I suppose it's OK, but if you're trying to get something done, and there's a free tool that does what you want, what's your objection to using it?

Comment: +1 Java Date/Time API is terrible, JodaTime is  a must for any Java developer who needs to do anything apart from trivial with dates-times.

Comment: @leonbloy: Well for anything serious (or really about time/calendar and not just an absolute time difference) sure, but would you import Joda Time when doing time measurements? (eg: start = Systems.nanoSeconds(); ... end = System.nanoSeconds(); time = ??). Especially I wouldn't even know what Joda Time would do with something like "28:00:00" - that's no valid time by any stretch of imagination (or are we talking about saturn time here? ;))

Comment: @Jim, I have no objection to using it. I just don't see why "Take a look at Joda-Time" is an answer...seems more like a "great" comment.

Comment: -1 : I don't see anything in the Joda-Time API that jumps out at me as a solution to the posters problem, since he isn't really dealing with `Time` as defined by Joda-Time. **Please point out the relevant Joda-Time API's**

Comment: @Jarrod: The Period class handles arbitrary periods of time and provides methods to add and subtract periods.

Comment: @leonbloy: The Period class handles periods like 28:00:00 just fine, it's a period of 28 hours.

Comment: @Jim - I don't see an API method or constructor anywhere that takes a `String` and converts it to anything useful.

Comment: @Jarrod: The Period class constructor with Object argument uses reflection to figure out the class and if it's a String, parses it according to a default format that can be changed.

Comment: @Jarrod no, it isn't 'needed', I agree. But it makes life a lot easier.

Comment: @Jarrod:  Part of the question was "Does any one know whether there are any Java libraries that can perform the subtraction."  Joda is such a library.  It's an answer, and a good one.

Comment: @Jim that is all well and good, but your answer, still is a non-answer. You might as well said, "use Google" and then followed up with "it is a search engine." Personally I still don't think Joda-Time is needed for simple math that isn't DateTime related

Comment: Hi guys, appreciate the discussion. We all have differing opinions on what constitute an answer. Well, suggestion of Joda-Time, imho appears to answer my question posed above. Having said that, it would be better if a short Joda-Time example can be furnished. I had been playing with Joda-Time last week and have not found it to work to my case. I may had been looking at the wrong area.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting time to seconds, subtract then convert back to simple time format.

Comment: Hi Mike V, I had converted it to millis, subtract and convert back to simple time format. You see, simple time format does not support hours greater than 24. I had coded it up last night and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how to get the difference between two Dates using [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) (which was mentioned by [Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison) earlier. It really is one of the best Time libraries available.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime timeA = new DateTime(2011, 6, 13, 12, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime timeB = new DateTime(2011, 6, 12, 23, 0, 0, 0);

    Period period = new Period(timeB, timeA);
    System.out.println(period.getHours());
  }
```

Comment: +1, for actually showing how the Joda-Time library would be used in such a scenario.

Comment: the question isn't about `Dates` it is about intervals formatted to look like a common time formatted string. What `DateTime` does **36:00:00.00** represent?

Comment: Hi bamana, I'm not subtracting date, but am really subtracting time. As you can see, the String "36:00:00.00" has a time component but not a date component. Hence, Jarrod Roberson is right.

Comment: Hi mre, the Joda-Time library will work for the scenario proposed by bamana. But does not work for my case. Nonetheless, good feedback.